# Is there a way to reduce the file size saved from a byte array in xamarin?

Tags: xamarin.forms, dependency-injection

Right now im trying to save an image using DI in Xamarin Forms, but the problem im facing now is that the file im saving is way bigger than the original file that im reading from (im using bitoobitImageEditor to load the file from my device). The original image is 200kb yet the image saved is 773kb. Is there something i can do about this?

this is my file saving function

```
public void SavePictureToDisk(string filename, byte[] imageData)
        {
            var dir = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDcim);
            var pictures = dir.AbsolutePath;
            //adding a time stamp time file name to allow saving more than one image... otherwise it overwrites the previous saved image of the same name  
            string name = filename + System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff") + ".jpeg";
            string filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(pictures, name);
            try
            {
                System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, imageData);
                
                //mediascan adds the saved image into the gallery  
                var mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionMediaScannerScanFile);
                mediaScanIntent.SetData(Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(new File(filePath)));
                Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context.SendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
            }
            catch (System.Exception e)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }

        }
```

and this is my photo reading function

```
public ICommand GalleryButton_Clicked => new Command(async () =>
        {
            frontimage = await ImageEditor.Instance.GetEditedImage(null, Config);
            if (frontimage != null)
            {
                PhotoImageFront.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(frontimage));
            }
        });
```

Comment: You could compress the image before you save it.

Comment: how do i go about doing that? is there a function that i could look at?

Comment: You could refer to [this](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/f140972dce41c90a5fbc4bca6671bf74d32ad700/XamFormsImageResize/XamFormsImageResize/ImageResizer.cs#L92).